# I want my output to be free of line breaks?

Tags: python, truthtable

```
table = [[False,False,False,False,False], [False,False,True,False,True]]
    
#not changes------------------
for lines in table:
    for item in lines:
        print("%s\t" % item)
    print("\n")
#-----------------------------
```

I want output is:

```
False False False False False
False False True False True
```

But my output is:

False
False
False
False
False

False
False
True
False
True

Comment: Your list is 3 deep - you need another loop to unpack the last  list.

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing - if you want no line breaks, can't you simply remove the `print("\n")`?

Comment: Also if you want to add a single newline, just do `print()` not `print("\n")`

Answer (score 1):

print() has some extra parameters, the defaults being

```py
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

Notice the `end='\n'` - basically whenever you call print(), `end` is added to the end of whatever you're printing. You'll want to remove this additional `\n` by doing `print(value, end='')`.

This will get you:

```py
False   False   False   False   False

False   False   True    False   True
```

which still doesn't seem to be what you want. Replacing the `\t` with   gets you a bit closer:

```py
False False False False False 

False False True False True
```

And finally, since you know `\n` is added to the end of `print()` by default, you can probably see why `print('\n')` will actually become `print('\n\n')` - if you replace your `print('\n')` with `print()`, you'll get your desired output:

```py
False False False False False 
False False True False True
```

Cheers

Comment: Also a little tip, rather than `print("%s " % item, end="")`, you could instead use `print(item, end=" ")`

Answer (score 0):

Option one:

```
table = [[False,False,False,False,False], [False,False,True,False,True]]
for lines in table:
    print(str(lines).replace('[', '').replace(']', ''))
```

Option two:

```
table = [[False,False,False,False,False], [False,False,True,False,True]]
for lines in table:
    print(','.join([str(item) for item in lines]))
```

Output:

```
False, False, False, False, False
False, False, True, False, True
```

Comment: i had edit asked sorry

Comment: edited the code to match :)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably leverage a pandas here:

```
table = [[False,False,False,False,False], [False,False,True,False,True]]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
        row.to_string(index=False).replace('\n', ' ')
```

output:

```
'False False False False False'
'False False  True False  True'
```

Comment: i had edit asked sorry

Comment: Updated an answer based on your edit in question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the brackets too, you need to nest one more loop which will unpack the elements of the most inner list and then add a new line for each inner list , as shown in the below code:

```
table = [[[False,False,False,False,False], [False,False,True,False,True]]
        ,[[False,False,False,False,False], [False,False,True,True,False,True,True]]]
    
#not changes------------------
for lines in table:
    for item in lines:
        for i in item:
            print("%s " % i, end='')# use '\t' if you need more space in between in print("%s\t" % i, end='')
        print()
#         print("%s\t" % item)... commenting this as not in use
    print()
#-----------------------------
```

Below is the output :

```
False False False False False 
False False True False True 

False False False False False 
False False True True False True True
```

Do let me know if this is what you wanted to do or not.

Comment: thank you, i have compelete

Comment: whether it was useful?